# PHP, регулярное выражение. Не работают квантификаторы при негативном просмотре

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Задача такая: извлечь из поста ссылки на картинки `(\<img src=...>)`, к которым не привязаны ссылки `(\<a href=...>)`. Написала такую регулярку:

```
preg_match_all ( '#(?<!<a[^>]*>)<img[^>]+src="(.*?)"#' , $content , $matches);
```

То есть берём инфу из тэга `\<img src>`, если перед ним нет тэга `\<a>`.

Но внутри скобок для негативного просмотра не работает квантификатор `*`, функция вообще не срабатывает. Меняла его на +, {1,}, *? - тоже не работает. Что интересно, если написать конкретное число повторений, то всё отрабатывает правильно!

```
preg_match_all ( '#(?<!<a[^>]{68}>)<img[^>]+src="(.*?)"#' , $content , $matches);
```

Подскажите, это особенности негативного/позитивного просмотра, или я что-то неправильно пишу? Если там действительно нельзя задать произвольное число повторений, может, подскажете альтернативное решение?

Comment: Да не нужны вам квантификаторы и негативный просмотр. Вам нужен `'#<a(?:\s[^>]*)?>.*?</a>(*SKIP)(*F)|<img[^>]+src="([^"]*)"#s'`

Comment: обычно для разбора HTML используют соответствующие средства, а не регулярные выражения.

Comment: Спасибо, Wiktor Stribiżew, Ваш вариант подошёл идеально! Не знала о таком способе. Хочу отметить Ваш ответ как решение, но не понимаю как: возле комментария не вижу никаких галочек, чтобы отметить.

Comment: @Turingvetil Я добавил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать

```
$pattern = '#<a(?:\s[^>]*)?>.*?</a>(*SKIP)(*F)|<img[^>]+src="([^"]*)"#s';
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
```

[Как работает это выражение?](https://regex101.com/r/wgEQNY/1)

- `<a` - текст `<a`
- `(?:\s[^>]*)?` - опциональная последовательность пробельного символа и ноля и более символов, отличных от `>`
- `>` - символ `>`
- `.*?` - ноль и более символов, как можно меньше
- `</a>` - текст `</a>`
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - то, что нашли, забудь и начни новый поиск с места, где сейчас находится индекс
- `|` - или
- `<img` - текст `<img`
- `[^>]+` - один и более символов, отличных от `>`
- `src="` - строка `src="`
- `([^"]*)` - Подмаска №1: ноль и более символов, отличных от `"`
- `"` - символ `"`.